# The same Makefile succeeded in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS but failed in Angstrom on Beagle Board

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I tried to compile `chardev.c` from this [tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x892.html) using the following `Makefile`:

```
obj-m   := chardev.o
KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD     := $(shell pwd)
default :
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

I got the correct output and it is working fine while I `make` in Ubuntu 10.04 LTC:

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-33-generic-pae/build M=/home/noge/Desktop/driver-            tutorial/IOCTL_example/ioctl_eclipse modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-33-generic-pae'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  LD [M]  /home/noge/Desktop/driver-tutorial/IOCTL_example/ioctl_eclipse/chardev.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-33-generic-pae'
```

However, when I transfer the same files to [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) that is running Angstrom, and did a `make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-`, I got the following error:

```
root@beagleboard:~/Desktop/noge/C-tutorials/hello_world# make CROSS_COMPILE=
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-                                                     
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32/build M=/home/root/Desktop/noge/C-tutorials/hels
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.32/2.6_kernel'                  
Makefile:1448: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.                      
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.32/2.6_kernel'                   
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

I'm not sure if this is the cause, but I noticed the version of `make` is different for the Ubuntu and Angstrom:

```
Angstrom's version:
GNU Make 3.82                                                                   
Built for arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi

Ubuntu's version:
GNU Make 3.81
This program built for i486-pc-linux-gnu
```

In short, why the error while doing `make` in Beagle Board running Anstrom?

Thanks for any help..!

Update:
The content of the Makefile near line 1448:

```
1447    # Modules
1448    / %/: prepare scripts FORCE
1449    $(Q)$(MAKE) KBUILD_MODULES=$(if $(CONFIG_MODULES),1) \
1450    $(build)=$(build-dir)
1451    %.ko: prepare scripts FORCE
1452    $(Q)$(MAKE) KBUILD_MODULES=$(if $(CONFIG_MODULES),1)   \
1453    $(build)=$(build-dir) $(@:.ko=.o)
1454    $(Q)$(MAKE) -f $(srctree)/scripts/Makefile.modpost
```

I did a check on my kernel version and I got:`Linux beagleboard 2.6.32 #3 PREEMPT Thu Jun 23 09:56:19 CEST 2011 armv7l GNU/Linux`, but the kernel source I got from [here](http://code.google.com/p/beagleboard/wiki/BeagleSourceCode) is of version `2.6.22.18`.

Is it possible for getting the wrong kernel source code that is causing this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure your Makefile is not at fault here, but there might be a rule name collision. What is at line 1448 of /usr/src/linux-2.6.32/2.6_kernel/Makefile ?